# Is there separator for options_for_select in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I use select tag for displaying names in options_for_select and i want to add a separator line in drop down list,under separator line i want to place a link to edit the all names.
For example.

```
Name1
name2
name3
-----
edit_names
```

this is my view code

```
= select_tag :page_names, options_for_select(pages.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}, params[:search]), {:class => 'auto-width'}
```

help me to solve this.

Answer (score 3):

This has the basics of what you are looking for

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-grouped_options_for_select

Answer (score 2):

you can do this using `insert` method of `Array` class like this

```
select_tag :page_names, options_for_select(pages.collect{|c| [c.name, c.id]}.insert(position,['-----',nil]), params[:search]), {:class => 'auto-width'}
```

here `position` is the index where you want to insert.......